# How to use windows Phone app for many resellers

Tags: windows-phone-7, namespaces, uninstallation

I want to have an app which i can use for many resellers. 
so for example my projectname / namespace etc. is myApp and now i want to copy all the stuff in a searate svn branch and rename some strings, change some pictures etc.

The problem is that if i install the copy (via visual Studio) my original app get uninstalled.

1. Does this also happen if the app comes via Store download?
2. how to prevent Windows Phone from uninstalling the first app when the second one is installed?

Thank you...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Windows Phone application is identified by its product ID, specified in the manifest. So, to answer your questions:

1. The issue won't happen on the store, because a new product ID will automatically be generated when you submit your app
2. To prevent the issue you're facing, just change the product ID in the `WMAppManifest.xml` file